# how do you format date time in python

Tags: python

I have a variable that has value like this:

```
val='14/12/15 0000'
```

it is in two digit year/month/day hourminute format.

I need to convert this to epoch time.

I tried this

```
import datetime

datetime.datetime.strptime(val, "%y/%m/%d %HH%MM").strftime('%s')
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: time data '14/12/15 0000' does not match format '%y/%m/%d %HH%MM'
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you check the docs?  They have a complete list of available format codes here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: @iCodez, yes, that's what I am doing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hours (24 hr) are `%H`, not `%HH`, and minutes are `%M`, not `%MM`.

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(val, "%y/%m/%d %H%M").strftime('%s')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [easy_date](https://github.com/ralphavalon/easy_date) to make it easy:

```
import date_converter
my_datetime = date_converter.string_to_string('14/12/15 0000', '%y/%m/%d %H%M', '%s')
```

Or even convert **directly** to a timestamp:

```
import date_converter
timestamp = date_converter.string_to_timestamp('14/12/15 0000', '%y/%m/%d %H%M')
```